# VB.NET If-Else in List

Tags: vb.net, list, conditional-statements, if-statement

I just want to know if there's an approach in VB.NET that can find if a specific value exist on a list or something which can use in my If-else condition. What I'm doing now is to use this:

```
If ToStatus = "1CE" Or ToStatus = "2TL" Or ToStatus = "2PM" Then
    'Do something
Else
    'Do something
End If
```

This works fine, but how if I have hundreds of string to compare to `ToStatus` in the future? It will be a nightmare! Now, if such functionality exists, how can I add "And" and "Or" in the statement?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `ToStatus` will never equal `1CE` and `2TL`.

Comment: @SlaKs - now it will! :)

Comment: Then you want to check whether it's _not_ in a list.

Comment: Rather than `Or` one should always use `OrElse` which is more performant.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the `Contains` function:

```
Dim someList = New List(Of String) From { ... }
If Not someList.Contains(ToStatus) Then
```

Comment: Could you pleas tell me what package should I include to get `List` working?

Comment: `List(Of T)` is part of the core BCL, in `System.Collections.Generic` in mscorlib.dll.

Comment: Hey, I know this i a different question but can I create an instance of `List(Of T)` without using `.add("My String")`? I mean like putting them in the constructor? 'Coz my real objective is to minimize the codes I'm writing.

Comment: `New List(Of String) From {"Tom", "Dick", "Harry"}`

Comment: @SLaks Thanks SLaks, wxactly what I needed. if you could edit your answer to include comment above that would make you answer even better.

Answer (score 7):

You can do the following:

```vb
If {"1CE","2TL","2PM"}.Contains(ToStatus) Then
    ' ...
End If
```

Answer (score 5):

Like [Slaks pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6727960/1366033), you can use `Contains` on an `enumerable` collection.  But I think readability suffers.  I don't care if some list ***contains*** my variable; I want to know if my variable is ***in*** some list.

You can wrap contains in an extension method like so:

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Module ExtensionMethods

    <Extension()> _
    Public Function [In](Of T)(ByVal item As T, ByVal ParamArray range() As T) As Boolean
        Return range.Cast(Of T).Contains(item)
    End Function

End Module
```

Then call like this:

```vb
If ToStatus.In("1CE","2TL","2PM") Then
```

Answer (score 4):

you may use select case

```vb
select case A
   case 5,6,7,8
       msgbox "you are in"
   case else
       msgbox "you are excluded"
end select
```

Answer (score 1):

**For .NET 2.0**

I came across another problem where SLaks solution won't work, that is if you use .NET 2.0 where method `Contains` is not present. So here's the solution:

```
If (Array.IndexOf(New String() {"1CE", "2TL", "2PM"}), ToStatus > -1) Then
    'Do something if ToStatus is equal to any of the strings
Else
    'Do something if ToStatus is not equal to any of the strings
End If
```

[VB.NET - Alternative to Array.Contains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775582/vb-net-alternative-to-array-contains)

Answer (score -1):

Remove duplicates from the list

```
Dim ListWithoutDuplicates As New List(Of String)
For Each item As String In ListWithDuplicates

    If ListWithoutDuplicates.Contains(item) Then

     ' string already in a list - do nothing

    Else

        ListWithoutDuplicates.Add(item)

    End If

Next
```