# Compact many ORs into one If Statement

Tags: vb.net

I want to use many OR statements in one IF statement, but obviously it ends up like this:

```
If x = this or x = that or x = these or x = those Then
```

Is there are way to compact this into one smaller statement?
e.g.

```
If x = {this, that, those, these}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VB.NET If-Else in List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727949/vb-net-if-else-in-list)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains?view=net-5.0) to determine if a list contains your value. Assuming integer

```
Dim vals As New List(Of Integer)(New Integer() {this, that, those})

If vals.Contains(x) Then
   ' do something
End If
```

Comment: In fact, you could probably do `If {this, that, those}.Contains(x) Then '...`.

Answer (score 0):

One could use `Select Case`for it. As an example just some code

```
Dim x As String
x = "this"
Select Case x
    Case "this", "that", "these","those"
        ' Do this that 
    Case "other this", "other that"
        ' do other this that 
    Case Else
End Select
```

Or you use a list as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727949/vb-net-if-else-in-list/6727960)